# GSON on Google App Engine throws a Security Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gson

I am trying to convert an object into JSON using the GSON library on Google App Engine. For some reason, it throws this exception and I don't understand how to solve this. Any suggestions?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private static final int java.util.BitSet.ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-8d5b435d6736643f(Request.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:29)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:141)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:123)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.getJsonElementForChild(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:148)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.addAsArrayElement(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:139)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitArray(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:83)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:109)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.getJsonElementForChild(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:148)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.addAsChildOfObject(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:126)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitArrayField(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:154)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:123)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContextDefault.serialize(JsonSerializationContextDefault.java:56)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:230)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:315)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:270)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:250)
    at companionmodel.Sample_Model_PopulateServlet.printOutput(Sample_Model_PopulateServlet.java:59)
    at companionmodel.Sample_Model_PopulateServlet.doGet(Sample_Model_PopulateServlet.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:250)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5838)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5836)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:398)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$2.run(Server.java:852)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:576)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.startRpc(Server.java:807)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server.processRequest(Server.java:369)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.ServerConnection.messageReceived(ServerConnection.java:442)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.parseMessages(RpcConnection.java:319)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcConnection.dataReceived(RpcConnection.java:290)
    at com.google.net.async.Connection.handleReadEvent(Connection.java:474)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.processNetworkEvents(EventDispatcher.java:831)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.internalLoop(EventDispatcher.java:207)
    at com.google.net.async.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.google.net.rpc.RpcService.runUntilServerShutdown(RpcService.java:251)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RpcRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:413)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code I am using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(modelObject);
```

Comment: This feature of reflection may simply not be available on App Engine. It's weird, though, that AccessibleObject is listed in the JRE whitelist: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for the reply. So that means I need to write my own toJSON methods :(

Comment: Reflection is available on App Engine - but it appears that that particular object is off-limits. Odd that the library even tries to access it, though - are you trying to serialize a BitSet over JSON?

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the pointers Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app engine does support reflection - however you are trying to reflect on a private field of a JRE class:

> Reflection
>
> An application is allowed full,
>   unrestricted, reflective access to its
>   own classes. It may query any private
>   members, use
>   java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(),
>   and read/set private members.
>
> **An application can also also reflect
>   on JRE and API classes**, such as
>   java.lang.String and
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.
>   **However, it can only access public
>   members of these classes, not
>   protected or private.**
>
> An application cannot reflect against
>   any other classes not belonging to
>   itself, and it can not use the
>   setAccessible() method to circumvent
>   these restrictions.

...from http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox:

I'd consider writing a custom serializer for Bitset.

See: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ

Also: http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/535892ffcf691aa/897f27e37e03ce58?lnk=gst&q=bitset#897f27e37e03ce58

http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/535892ffcf691aa

Comment: Thank You. I guess in my case, I am not sure why GSON is doing what it is doing :) If you know of any other ways of getting it work, it would be awesome.

Comment: No wukkas.  Perhaps regisiter a custom serializer for Bitset?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct GsonBuilder with .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation(), and mark all serialized fields with @Expose annotation. In this case, Gson doesn't try to serialize fields other that you want.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
String json = gsonBuilder.create().toJson(modelObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

If App Engine does not support Reflection, then we are pretty much left to write our own toJSON method. This can be done as follows (not a big deal but someone might find it useful):

```
public SampleObject {

  //...

  /**
   * Convert this object to a JSON object for representation
   */
  public JSONObject toJSON() {
    try {
       JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
       jsonobj.put("id", this.id);
       jsonobj.put("name", this.name);
       return jsonobj;
    } catch(Exception e) {
       return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can use a toString method on this object to print out the JSON representation. Not the best I agree but some workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem recently.

I was running  Gson to parse JSON and it worked well for a long time so I didn't worry about GAE not allowing Reflection on it's platform.

I introduced a HashMap the Form class and it worked well in my local system with Gson doing JSON Parse perfectly.

But when I deployed that code to the Google App Engine Cloud it failed with the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private final int java.lang.ThreadLocal.threadLocalHashCode
```

So now I've switched to Jackson JSON Parser which is faster and does not use reflection - but yes - more work.