# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gson

Simply put, when deploying my (Java) app to GAE, GAE throws an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for a class in one of the bundled jars.
I use GSON in GAE but it can't work and I already import GSON-2.2.4.jar
I don't know how to solve it .

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
>       at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:89)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:82)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:254)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
>       at test.client.CatchData.getData(CatchData.java:135)
>       at test.client.Main.run(Main.java:56)
>       at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:69)
>       ... 66 more

Comment: Enviroment : jdk1.7.0_25 & GWT SDK 2.6.0 & App Engine SDK 1.9.7 & Eclipse 3.7

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002714/gson-on-google-app-engine-throws-a-security-exception

Answer (score 0):

From  Google App Engine [Java Runtime Environment](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1):

**The sandbox**

To allow App Engine to distribute requests for applications across multiple web servers, and to prevent one application from interfering with another, the application runs in a restricted "sandbox" environment. In this environment, the application can execute code, store and query data in the App Engine datastore, use the App Engine mail, URL fetch and users services, and examine the user's web request and prepare the response.

An App Engine application cannot:

- write to the filesystem. Applications must use the App Engine datastore for storing persistent data. Reading from the filesystem is allowed, and all application files uploaded with the application are available.
- respond slowly. A web request to an application must be handled within a few seconds. Processes that take a very long time to respond are terminated to avoid overloading the web server.
- make other kinds of system calls.